# ScriptResource.axd and local ISA proxy server

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Does anybody experienced issue with ISA proxy server, blocking(!!) ScriptResource.axd request to external webserver?

Site is configured on IIS6 and when I check in FireBug, it shows following message:

```
* Error Code: 500 Internal Server Error. De aanvraag wordt niet ondersteund.
```

for ScriptResource.axd request.

then part of page is empty and further leads to sys is undefined as JavaScript is not loaded.

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever resolve this, was it related to SharePoint?

Comment: Yes it's resolved but was not related to share point but ISA. If you have similar problem, I can share the the solution which worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Actually the error code was 50, ISA logging:  Request is not supported.

AccessRuleSendAcceptEncodingHeader was the problem in ISA 2004, there is no settings in ISA which will let you set this parameter to true.

What we did is: Create a script to set AccessRuleSendAcceptEncodingHeader to true as per

http://support.microsoft.com/?id=927263.

You can also find script code to disable it again.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably to do with being an .axd or the fact that your ISa server is clustered and there is a machinekey mismatch...

Comment: Thanks for reply I appreciate it but ISA is not clustered and machine key mismatch can be overruled(?) as its not for all *.axd requets, its only one request causing this. when we access site from outside its works. we are not sure whats special in that request causing ISA to block it or hinder it some way. Please suggest. Thanks